# localhost doesn't work after upgrade to Mountain Lion

Tags: apache, upgrade, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to Mountain Lion from Lion and everything is just like I had on Lion, except for localhost. I start apache from terminal and it starts fine. however, I can't get to localhost, it gives me the error "can't connect to server localhost".

I have checked my `httpd.conf` file and it is just like before when it used to work. The only difference after upgrade was the removal of `username.conf` from `users` folder in apache2 directory, which I recreated.

apache error log file doesn't show anything either. in fact, there is NO any log file in there.

Has anyone got a solution for that?